# How do I delete this folder in Solaris?

Tags: solaris

I am not sure how or when the below folder was created.. But I am unable to delete or open it..

```
bash-3.2$ cd '+%d-%m-%y'
bash: cd: +%d-%m-%y: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$ rm -f  '+%d-%m-%y'
bash-3.2$ ls -l | grep "+"
drwxr-xr-x   2 hypess   hypess         2 Dec 20 04:21 +%d-%m-%y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes. Not double quotes. Also use `-r` to remove directories:

```
rm -r '+%d-%m-%y'
```

Not There may be some (leading or) trailing whitespace. You can reveal this using:

```
ls -l | grep "+" | cat -vet
```

Ensure you capture all of the whitespace in the quotes.

How it was created? `hypess` used single quotes, presumable after a malformed `date` command.

When it was created? Around `2 Dec 20 04:21`, I suspect.

Comment: Updated my question. That is not the issue...

Comment: @KentPawar: I've updated my answer accordingly. I'm not sure it warranted a downvote as it was a reasonable response to the question as it stood at the time with double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks @Johnsyweb! Turns out the script was using Windows EOL and so the folder `'+%d-%m-%y^M$'` was created along with the `CR` special character..

Comment: Nasty! Glad you found it.